# Creating Heat Map using Krigging

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, interpolation, kriging

I'm trying to create a good heat map using Krigging for missing values. 
[image: Data with RLevels]

I have the following data, that contains all the values that have been measured for RLevel.

I followed the following link that tells how to use krigging. https://rpubs.com/nabilabd/118172

This is the following code I wrote. Before these steps, I had removed all the values from my DieData that 
needed values to be tested. The values that need to be tested are refered as die.data.NAValues in my code.

```
#**************************************************CODE***************** 
#Step3: Convert to SpatialPointsDataFrame Object 
coordinates(die.data) = ~X+Y 

#Step 4: Get the prediction Grid 
coordinates(die.data.NAValues)=~X+Y 


#Using autokride method 
kr = autoKrige(RLevel, die.data, die.data.NAValues,nmax=20) 
predicted_die_values <- kr$krige_output 
predicted_die_model <- kr$var_model 


#Get Predictions. Plot the predicted on heat map. 
g <- gstat(NULL,"RLevel",RLevel~1,die.data, model=predicted_die_model,nmax=1) 
predictedSet <- predict(g,newdata=die.data,BLUE=TRUE) 

#Plot the krigging graph 
predicted_die_values %>% as.data.frame %>% ggplot(aes(x=X,y=Y)) + geom_tile(aes(fill=v1.pred))+coord_equal() +scale_fill_gradient(low="yellow",high="red")+scale_x_continuous()+scale_y_continuous()+theme_bw()
```

When I plot the graph, I get the following image from  the values that have been tested by the KRIGING METHOD. 
[image]

My question is how can I show a good heat map with predicted points from KRIG and from the points already have. I want my graph to show something like this from the link above I had posted. [image]

Description about my dataset: My original dataset including NA values that have not been tested contains around 55057 points. When I take out NA values and use that are my prediction grid, I get 390 points. Majority of the values for RLevel are within 30's range except around 100-200 points are above 100.

Can anyone help me out or give me guidance of how to produce a good heatmap?